# JAX-RS, path params don't work

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, path-parameter

I try to pass a parameter via GET to a REST method.

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
public Response getUser(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    Query qry = em.createQuery("from User c WHERE id = :user_id");
    qry.setParameter("user_id", id);
    List<User> results = qry.getResultList();

    if(results.size() > 0) {
        return Response.ok(results.get(0),MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build();
    } else {
        return Response.serverError().status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }
}
```

If I call it via the Rest Client with:

```
client = ClientBuilder.newClient();    
Response response = client.target(TestPortProvider.generateURL("/user")+"/abc").request().get(Response.class);
```

then the method gets called but the parameter is empty. If I remove the `"abc"` from the GET url the method gets not called. Also if I remove the `@Path("{id}")` it doesn't work too. It seems as there is a parameter but it's empty for no reason. Maybe some one can help me to fix the problem.

kind regards

Answer (score 16, accepted):

sadly the reason was a wrong import for PathParam. so a big note to my desk ... if unchecked things doesn't work ... check your imports that are generated by your IDE.

Comment: Happened the same to me, I was going crazy!

Comment: ya same here.Thanks!!

Comment: you saved me.  imported javax.websocket.server.PathParam

Answer (score 6):

`{}` is not required in the method parameter, just give the name.  Try the following:

```
 public Response getUser(@PathParam("id") String id)
```

Comment: My bad, fixed this mistake but it's still empty :/

Answer (score 4):

The import can get defaulted to:

```
import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
```

Replace it with the one from the JAX-RS API:

```
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason it would have not worked is the wrong import for **PathParam**. So import the javax.ws.rs.PathParam and check it again.